# Qt Read memory pointer value

Tags: c++, qt, memory

I need help for this method.

I use same code with C++ but on Qt value don't are same example

```
DWORD address = 0x004D2004;
DWORD offset = 0x4;
int value=0;

ReadProcessMemory(_hwnd,(void*)address + offset,&value,(DWORD)sizeof(value));
QMessageBox::Information(this,QString::number(value),tr("Value is:"),QMessageBox::ok);
```

Without Qt if i read the result example are: 5

else i try to read value with Qt, value are example: 49951447

anoyone know a solution?

Comment: Are you saying that in the same process you read value ONCE then you print it with some standard function you get 5 and print it again using QString::number and you receive 49951447 ?

Comment: I read from an external process a value of an address retrieved via offsets .

If I try to recover the value of the same code from Qt C ++ I get 49951447.
If I try with another ide , in my case I codeblock get exactly the value 5 .with the same code I get two different values ​​. On codeblock works . While Qt C ++ does not work well .

Comment: Can you debug in both IDE?  Probably it will be the easiest way to find the difference

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're compiling as administrator.

Make sure you're compiling for the same bitness as the target process, x86 for x86, x64 for x64.

Your call to ReadProcessMemory() is missing the last argument which is the "number of bytes read".  You will want to check that for error checking.

call GetLastError() after the call to ReadProcessMemory() as well as checking the return value of ReadProcessMemory() for error checking.

These tips will solve your problem.